# How to Connect Mongodb to tableau

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api

We are still in the development phase.
Our req is parse the XML to JSON and store them as flat files in Mongodb
Then for the analysis we want to use tableau.
Part 1 of the req is done...now i need to connect to tableau.

Versions we have are
Mongo 3.2
Tableau 9.1

I have googled and couldn't find any steps to integrate tableau with mongodb.
I also saw Mongodb has released a connector but there is no Windows BI connector.

Now do we need to migrate to Enterprise version for tableau connectivity.

Many thanks for the inputs

Comment: Here's a link with resources to connect to mongodb. Have you tried this? https://community.tableau.com/thread/151497

Comment: thts a paid version.I have seen this post in tableau.I am looking for some thing with postGRESQL and on mongoend.

Answer (score 3):

### Detailed Instructions (for Windows), using localhost server of mongoDB:

1) Installation: Install Tableau, MongoDB, and MongoDB BI Connector for Tableau.

2) From the command prompt, you will want to serve your mongoDB instance as well as the mongoDB_sql server needed to connect to Tableau MongoDB BI Connector. Add mongoDB and mongoDB BI Connector bin's to your system path, for example: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\` and 2) `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Connector for BI\2.3\bin\`.

3) Serve your local mongoDB server. Example command: `mongod`. (Let's assume it is served on `localhost:27017`.

4) Create a schema of the database you want Tableau to integrate with. Command to do this: `mongodrdl --out <path_that_you_want_to_save_schema_to> /db:<name_of_database>`

5) Validate the schema, and serve your local server of mongoDB as an SQL server (Tableau expects this server to be running). Command to do this: `mongosqld --schema <path_to_schema>` (** this will typically serve to `localhost:3307`)

6) You can now go to Tableau, under connectors, click on the MongoDB BI Connector, and enter `localhost` for the server, and `3307` for the port. (assuming in step 5 you have validated that the sql server is running on localhost with port 3307).

I hope this helps, these exact steps worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

The mongo biconnector is implemented as a multicorn (python) based Foreign Data Wrapper imbedded in the supplied postgresql server. Tools are provided to set up the postgresql "biuser" user, to create the collection to table mappings from data sampling, and to import the resultant schema into postgresql. The postgresql database contains non-materialized views corresponding to the (flattened) mongo collections. Access is through the postgresql server using standard postgresql jdbc/odbc drivers.

Answer (score -1):

I think run **mongodb bi connector** in docker ubuntu/centos is a choice if the connector does not support windows, and tableau does not support linux, that's a question.

There is an example of create bi connection in [www.mongodb.com/tableau](https://www.mongodb.com/tableau) with mongosqld

Hope this would work well for your issue

Answer (score -1):

I have described our way connecting to data in MongoDB Community Edition to Tableau. First creat an API to your DB, then Web Data Connector to Tableau (it's HTML and JS files), after you can use WDC Connector in Tableau to connect to your URL.

Here is the detailed description how we did it: https://medium.com/@katya.neulinger/tableau-web-data-connector-to-mongodb-c1477d7d5ac9